# Magento 1.9.2.2 Order Confirmation Email Not Sent To Customers

Tags: magento

I have done virtually everything but this problem persists. Upon creating an order, the customer does not receive a confirmation email. The problem started some 6 months ago and it was On and Off until a month ago when it ceased sending completely. Please does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? Thanks.

NB: The cron is set correctly and is working properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Please check whether `Cron jobs` are working or not, you can check easily by installing `AOE SCHEDULER` extension, make sure you have proper setting in `System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron` Also check whether you entered sender email in `System > configuration> Sales> Sales email > Order emails`.

Comment: Please Refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45571/new-order-email-confirmation-not-being-sent

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 1.9.1 and above versions, the emails are not being sent directly during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cron jobs. Please ensure your cron jobs has been set up and is running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ist check your cron  if cron is running mail is definetly send other wise 1 more option you can take just do small change in core file-

`Template.php` is located in => `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
   use

if (!$this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```